How to work with LinkedMap<String, dynamic> returned by firestore query flutter
I'm watching a StreamProvider and one of the fields of the returned  result is a LinkedMap<String,dynamic>
 final result=ref.watch(documentStreamProvider);

 return result. When(data: (data){
 for (var doc in data.docs) {
   final Map<String,dynamic> newDoc=doc.data() as Map<String,dynamic>;
   final newMap = newDoc["taskForDate"] ;// LinkedMap<String,dynamic>
  }

here is the structure of the data written to firestore
data = {
    "date": dateId,
     "taskForDate":{
        keyId: {
          "name": textEditingContrller.value.text,
          "status": false
               }
                   }
      };
 documentPath.set(data,SetOptions(merge: true));

how to work with LinkedMap in flutter or convert it a normal map ?
